# Get element current position?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there a way to get the element's current position? it's x and y. I tried `getLocationOnScreen` and `getLocationInWindow` but the result was undefined.

Comment: depends on which element you are trying to get position, some elements like `span` doesn't support such methods

Answer (score 6):

I think the `getLocationOnScreen` and `getLocationInWindow` should be object, `getLocationOnScreen().x`  or `.y`   will be OK.